# Why can't I copy files on a flashdrive between my Xbox 360 and my computer?

Tags: borderlands

I copied a Borderlands save-game (from my Xbox 360) to my flash drive but when I plug it in to my computer, nothing shows up. The flash drive has nothing on it but that file. When I plug the flash drive to the Xbox 360 it works properly.

What's wrong?

Comment: You're trying to copy a Borderlands save from the 360 to PC?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, it would be impossible to copy a savegame file between the Xbox 360 and PC/Mac versions of most games, Borderlands included. If I remember correctly, the Xbox actually reformats (or perhaps partitions?) part of the flash drive (or other removable disk) for its own files, therefore rendering it rather useless on a PC. I expect the game software couldn't read the other save-files anyway.

Comment: However, you *can* back up Xbox files to external storage for use on your Xbox again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's pretty tricky. I've seen people transfer 360 saves to PC for Mass Effect 1/2 and [modify 360 Skyrim saves on the PC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTg-U8atbR0). (At 4:04 you can see he uses a special program to read the gamer profile stored on the drive, and at 4:19 you can even see a Borderlands save)

Try the method described in the video (starts at 3:31) for getting saves off your USB stick. It looks like you can't use the exact same save, but [you can transfer your gear, level, proficiencies etc. from one save to another](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=116173), *360 and PC included*.